# Alert if a remote computer tries to connect on a given port

Tags: windows-7, security, internet, firewall

I am looking for a Windows 7 program that can give an alert if a remote computer tries to connect on a given port, and gives the option to accept or refuse. I don't want any warning regarding other ports. I am not sure which firewall allows that. Gratis is better. Ideally, it should remember the decisions, i.e., maintain a whitelist of IPs.

Comment: [GlassWire](https://www.glasswire.com/features/) has remote server monitoring and an ask to connect popup feature but I don't think it applies to specific ports, where you looking for software that popups for each new port it connects to or just something where it would allow all ports for a given executable?

Comment: @Tom  software that popups each time a non-whitelisted IP tried to connect to a port that I specified. (I don't care about other port)

Comment: ok, that software isn't going to work - is there a price cap?

Comment: @Tom Not really, just browsing existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Most antivirus suites have a version that comes bundled with a firewall which supports this.

[Example interaction dialog](http://postimg.org/image/3s1jss5yf/) for ESET Smart Security firewall

There are some firewall-only products which also have some free versions (Comodo, ZoneAlarm, etc) but in my experience, the free versions are limited (sometimes unintentionally), provide less info, have a much worse user experience and, last but certainly not least, are known to get Windows in trouble when certain exotic conditions occur and all Windows network connectivity becomes broken.